# Import-Export class in js

Tags: javascript, object, import, export

I have a problem when I try to import class in js:

```js
//file 1
export default class myClass {
  constructor(){
    this.name = "name1";
  }
  saysHello(){
   console.log("hello"+this.name1);
  }
};
```

```js
//file 2
import { myClass } from 'file1.js'

//I have tried different alternatives

// alternative 1:
var v1 = new myClass();
v1.saysHello()

//alternative 2:
myClass.saysHello()

//alternative 2:
var v1 = Object.create(myClass);
```

In all alternatives I have the same error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'myClass' before initialization
>  http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/file2.js

In the html :

```html
  <script type="module" src="./js/file1.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="./js/file2.js"></script>
```

Comment: `import { myClass } from 'file1.js'` should be `import myClass from 'file1.js'` or *alternatively* `export default class myClass` should be `export class myClass` - you cannot import a default export with `{ }` - you either need the default import or to have a named export. With that said, this shouldn't lead to the error you've reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//file 2
import  myClass from './file-1.js'

//I have tried different alternatives

// alternative 1:
var v1 = new myClass();
v1.saysHello()
```

Comment: try this out Your ```Import syntax``` in default export is not correct

Comment: put ```'./file-1.js'``` relative to file path